# iOS: obtain a matrix from dictionary

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have an array of dictionary organized in this way:

```
[0] {@"code", 1} {@"category","drink"} ...and other value that aren't important
[1] {@"code", 2} {@"category","drink"}
[2] {@"code", 3} {@"category","drink"}
[3] {@"code", 4} {@"category","food"}
[4] {@"code", 5} {@"category","food"}
[5] {@"code", 6} {@"category","drink"}
```

what's the best way to obtain a matrix (array of arrays) in this way...

```
[0] {1,2,3,6}
[1] {4,5}
```

can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you have your array of dictionaries:

```
NSArray *originalArray = @[
    @{@"code": @1, @"category":@"drink"},
    @{@"code": @2, @"category":@"drink"},
    @{@"code": @3, @"category":@"drink"},
    @{@"code": @4, @"category":@"food"},
    @{@"code": @5, @"category":@"food"},
    @{@"code": @6, @"category":@"drink"}
];
```

You can get what you want via something like:

```
NSMutableArray *arrayOfCategories = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *arrayOfArrayOfCodes = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSDictionary *originalArrayEntry in originalArray)
{
    NSString *category = originalArrayEntry[@"category"];
    NSString *code = originalArrayEntry[@"code"];

    NSInteger indexInArrayOfCategories = [arrayOfCategories indexOfObject:category];
    NSMutableArray *arrayOfCodes;
    if (indexInArrayOfCategories == NSNotFound)
    {
        indexInArrayOfCategories = [arrayOfCategories count];
        arrayOfCodes = [NSMutableArray array];
        [arrayOfArrayOfCodes addObject:arrayOfCodes];
        [arrayOfCategories addObject:category];
    }
    else
    {
        arrayOfCodes = arrayOfArrayOfCodes[indexInArrayOfCategories];
    }

    [arrayOfCodes addObject:code];
}

NSLog(@"arrayOfArrayOfCodes = %@", arrayOfArrayOfCodes);
NSLog(@"arrayOfCategories = %@", arrayOfCategories);
```

Note you didn't ask for the array of category values, but I think the result set you asked for is meaningless in the absence of it.

Personally, if I wanted to accomplish what you asked for (and eliminate the need of that separate array) and order wasn't important, I might lean towards a dictionary (keyed by the category values) with a value of the array of codes, e.g. something that results from:

```
NSMutableDictionary *resultDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

for (NSDictionary *originalArrayEntry in originalArray)
{
    NSString *category = originalArrayEntry[@"category"];
    NSString *code = originalArrayEntry[@"code"];

    NSMutableArray *arrayForCategory = resultDictionary[category];
    if (!arrayForCategory)
    {
        arrayForCategory = [NSMutableArray array];
        resultDictionary[category] = arrayForCategory;
    }

    [arrayForCategory addObject:code];
}

NSLog(@"resultDictionary = %@", resultDictionary);
```

Comment: +1. I think your first code is what he meant. An array of arrays with the values of unique codes.

Comment: @ACB Agreed. But the array of array of code values is meaningless without the other array of category values. And whenever I end up with an array of values and another array of keys, I always think about possibly using a dictionary, hence my second suggestion, as I think it's a possibility the OP might want to contemplate.

Comment: Yes, that is true. I am not sure what he is planning to do with just an array of array of codes without category.